# Bounty link to Help Center instead of old FAQ page

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, help-center

I [just saw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16986206/1983854) a question with a Bounty.

> This question has an open [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) worth +50 reputation from Nitsan
>   Wakart ending in 6 days.

The link in the word "Bounty" is to https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty that then is redirected to the new one https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty .

Shouldn't the link be updated to the new one https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty?

Comment: I think this is more of a philosophical question.

Comment: The new help center is still evolving, give it some time. :)

Comment: This is [meta-tag:status-bydesign] unless you wanted to discuss the existential aspects.

Comment: Errr I thought it was just a bug, as the Help Center was just launched.

Comment: It redirects to the right place, so it's not really something that needs attention right now - but yes, eventually we'll try to update all of our post notices and error messages to eliminate any reference to FAQ in text or links.

Comment: OK. I still don't understand the use of a link (faq#bounty) that is immediately redirected to another page (help/bounty), but of course is your decision and in fact it is not important at all. Thanks, @Laura!

Comment: This seems to have been fixed a while back, unless I'm missing something. I'm gonna go ahead and mark it as [status-completed].